# How to find the LENGTH of key NAMES in a javascript object instead of length of content

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

In a javascript object, How do I find the length of key names?

```
Johnny:  7
William: 235
Betty:   16
```

I know `object.Betty.length` should return a `2`,
but I'm looking for how to see if the key-name Betty's `length` = 5.

I know the length of the entire object is 3. I now that is a different question, and NOT what I'm looking for.

I will be using a for (`var y in object`) line to cycle through it,
and if-logic to only display people with (for example) 7 letter names.

Would it be easier to convert the object or temporarily create an array to count with instead?

Comment: `y.length` is the length of the key

Comment: console.log(People['Betty'.length]    returns 'undefined'

Comment: `'Betty'.length` is just `5`, so that's the same as `console.log( People[ 5 ] );` which I guess is `undefined`. Why do you expect it to be something other than `undefined`?

Comment: console.log(People['Betty'] returns 16 - Trying to find out how to get the "5" for length of key name

Comment: `'console.log( Betty'.length );`, or, if `'Betty'` is in a variable called `y`: `console.log( y.length );`

Comment: Betty is the key inside the object. Trying to find the length returns the length of what is stored INSIDE the key 'Betty', but I want the length of the key-name, NOT it's contents.

Comment: `'console.log( Betty'.length );`, or, if `'Betty'` is in a variable called `y`: `console.log( y.length );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could iterate the keys of the object and get the length.

```js
var object = { Johnny: 7, William: 235, Betty: 16 },
    key;
    
for (key in object) {
    console.log(key, key.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can iterate through the keys using `Object.keys(obj).forEach()` and get the length of string using `length` like

```js
var obj = { Johnny: 7, William: 235, Betty: 16 }

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
   console.log(key, key.length)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this bunch of code will help you :)

```js
var data = {
  Johnny: 7,
  William: 235,
  Betty: 16
}

let getDicKeys = Object.keys(data);
getDicKeys.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(item.length);
});
```